# How to get base conda installation directory (not CONDA_PREFIX)?

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables, conda, environment

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get the base conda installation directory.

I wrote this but I know this isn't the best way to do it:

```
(base) -bash-4.2$ which conda
/usr/local/devel/ANNOTATION/jespinoz/anaconda3/bin/conda

(base) -bash-4.2$ which conda | python -c "import sys; print('/'.join(sys.stdin.read().split('/')[:-2]))"
/usr/local/devel/ANNOTATION/jespinoz/anaconda3
```

Is there some environment variable I'm missing?

Comment: Why not use `CONDA_PREFIX`?

Comment: Conda prefix is for the current environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick is to echo `CONDA_PREFIX` from activated **base**:

```bash
conda run -n base bash -c "echo \${CONDA_PREFIX}"
```

There is also `CONDA_ROOT`, but I don't think that is defined when no environment is activated.

Comment: Didn’t know conda run was a thing but that’s amazing